# Ionic : how to deeply customize ion-toggle?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, toggle, ion-toggle

Within Ionic, I am trying to customize `<ion-toggle>` but I face an issue of toggle selection in css.
I have 2 `<ion-toggle>` and when I design them in css they are both customized : that's correct. Issue coming if I want give both different custom ! 
I haven't found a way to put any class="xxx" on them allowing me to customize them separately.

Beyond they are `<ion-toggle>` classes I'd like to design on css

```
// .toggle : global sensitive toggle area
// .handle : circle above the toggle area 
// .toggle input : .handle moving area
// .toggle input+.track : .handle moving area when .handle at left
// .toggle input:checked+.track : .handle moving area when .handle at right
```

Even if I give a class to `<ion-toggle>` : `<ion-toggle class"xxx">`, there is no way to select it in css by : nor `.toggle.xxx{border:......}`, neither `.xxx{.....}`.

Please, does somebody knows how to dissociate these `<ion-toggle>` classes for many `<ion-toggle>`s ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found from the [ionic documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionToggle/)

By adding toggle-class="xxx" into  :

```
<ion-toggle toggle-class="MyCustomClass" ng-repeat="item in settingsList" ng-model="item.checked" ng-checked="item.checked"> {{ item.text }} </ion-toggle>
```

CSS example :

```
.toggle-search .handle{
  height: 13px!important;
  width: 13px!important;

}

.toggle-search input+.track {
  height: 15px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code for ionic toggle

.sign_toggle .toggle .handle{
width: 45px;
height: 47px;
}

.sign_toggle .toggle .track{
width: 97px;
height: 52px;
}

.sign_toggle .toggle input:checked + .track .handle {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(20px, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(51px, 0, 0);
background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

Add `ion-toggle` component to the HTML and simply add the attribute `class` with a class name:

```
<ion-toggle class="Awesome"></ion-toggle>
```

#### SCSS

Since `ion-toggle` is a native Ionic component in order to be able do customize it you must add the style on a global SCSS file. For example `global.scss`. If you add the style to a component SCSS file it won't work. **So make sure it's a global SCSS file.**

```
ion-toggle {

    &.Awesome {
        --background: ...;
        --background-checked: ...;
        --border-radius: ...;
        --handle-background: ...;
        --handle-background-checked: ...;
        --handle-border-radius: ...;
        --handle-box-shadow: ...;
        --handle-height: ...;
        --handle-max-height: ...;
        --handle-spacing: ...;
        --handle-transition: ...;
        --handle-width: ...;  
    }
}
```

However not everything can be customized directly with SCSS. Check the official docs to know what can fit your needs. Documentation: [Ionic - Ion Toggle - CSS Custom Properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toggle#css-custom-properties).

#### Deep Customization

If you want to apply deep customization to the `ion-toggle` component you can use a trick called HTML & CSS injection with Javascript and/or use browser devtools in your favor to find the names of elements and classes you want to customize.

[image]

#### Ionic & Angular Specifications

This answer was tested on the following Ionic & Angular specifications:

```
Ionic CLI                     : 6.17.1
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.8.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.1.4
@angular/cli                  : 12.1.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than dissociating classes the good practice would be to override those classes with custom css. Inspect DOM to see what specific classes and css properties to override.